# pyplot - Is there a way to explicitly specify the x and y axis numbering?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm displaying an image and want to specify the x and y axis numbering rather than having row and column numbers show up there.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Aha, one needs to use the "extent" argument, as in:

plt.imshow(H, cmap=plt.gray(), extent=[-5, 3, 6, 9])